# When will the digest cycle be triggered, if at all?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small problem, I am using a route like

```
.when('/beta/profiles/new', {
  controller: 'ProfilesController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'profiles/new.html',
  resolve: {
    action: function() { return "new"; }
  }
})
.when('/beta/profiles/index', {
  controller: 'ProfilesController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: 'profiles/index.html',
  resolve: {
    action: function() { return "index"; }
  }
})
```

now in my controller I have something like this:

```
function ProfilesController(profileService, action) {
  var vm = this,
      permittedActions = ["index", "new"];
  var actions = {
    index: function() {
      vm.hideProfile = {
        currentProfile: null,
        showModal: false,
        setCurrentProfile: function(profile_id) { this.currentProfile = profile_id },
        toggleHide: function() {/*...*/}
      }
      profileService.all().then(function(data) {
        vm.profiles = data.result;
      })
    },
    new: {/*.. */}
  }
  if(permittedActions[action] > -1) actions[action]();
}
```

now my question is if I hit a link (in the header,lets say) multiple times in succession, each time I hit `profiles/index.html` should it re-initialize everything ?

if I want to takethe advantage of angular's dirty checking thing should I put the vm.hideProfile out of the `index` function ? and If I do that should I also not do the same with vm.profiles = [];?

how/what can I do to check if variables are getting re-initialized and angular's dirty checking is not in play, or is it just common sense!! or should I just have a separate controller for each action?

and in case of re-initialization, is there any better way so that I can keep the hideProiles inside the index because I really don't need my new and show actions to know about `hideProfile`, since its unnecessary?

Comment: Each time you enter a view you will get a new controller/template created. Therefore when you to a different view and come back, you are getting a new controller. Dirty checking really only applies to variables/properties that you bind to (with {{ }} expressions). Finally, if you want to preserve some state, do that in an Angular service or factory (they are singletons that will only be created once in the life of your app).

Comment: @SunilD. so if I just click on link that takes me to the `profiles/index` page 5 times in succession, then each time there is a new controller? so then it wouldn't really matter if I write it inside the index function or not ?

Comment: No, I doubt that will happen. It will load a new controller the first time. When you click the link a  second time, the route is not changing, so there's no need to instantiate a new controller/view.

Comment: @SunilD. In my view I have a ng-click="vm.hiddenProfile.setCurrentProfile(profile.id)" like here http://plnkr.co/edit/WNoo8jPTz3GwdA5b1u5V?p=info it wouldn't matter if I put that inside the `index`, or maybe it will be helpful if you can say if there is any real difference between put the vm.hiddenProfile = {} inside and outside the `index` function

Answer (score 0):

A few things that hopefully can help:

1. Dirty checking is for objects bound to an active $scope (and $rootScope). https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope
2. To use $scope in your controller, (a) inject it. e.g. ProfilesController($scope, profileService, action), (b) put things on it, e.g. $scope.vm = vm;
3. looking at your code, the raw initialization should be super fast.
4. Don't think javascript is secure. If security is a real concern for your app, protect at the server.

Lastly on app arch, since angular is an MVC framework: define functions in your controller, and connect them to actions in the view via $scope. eg

```
$scope.index = function() { // do stuff 
  if (action !== "index") {return}; // disallowed by route
  //continue
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing those out, and also .. $scope is not needed to inject unless I am doing like $scope.$watch or apply, `this` refers to scope inside the controller.